# Ubuntu and NTFS copying failed

Tags: mount, ntfs

I have 2 partitions on my Ubuntu 10.10, one is ext4 for the system, another is NTFS for my data. While copying my files from my flash disk to NTFS partition (via terminal cp -r command), the light has turned off, and now I am unable to mount my NTFS partition, it says that:

```
Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 1: helper failed with:
mount: only root can mount /dev/sda6 on /media/sda6
```

When I try to Check for errors it says that: File system is clear

Some advices?

Output of sudo fdisk -l:

```
Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System
/dev/sda1 * 1 6201 49803264 83 Linux
/dev/sda2 6201 60802 438580225 5 Extended
/dev/sda5 6201 6325 999424 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6 6326 60802 437579776 7 HPFS/NTFS
Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System
/dev/sdb1 1 121602 976762583+ ee GPT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to boot from Windows, to be able to repair NTFS partition, and it was successfully. I deleted the folder that causes problems.